# Is $p(x)dx$ the probability to belong to $[x-dx/2 ; x+dx/2]$ or to $[x ; x+dx]$?

Tags: integration

Is $p(x)dx$ the probability to belong to $[x-dx/2 ; x+dx/2]$ or to $[x ; x+dx]$ ?

Are the two ones valid ?

Comment: They are equal, but both are unrigorous

Comment: @Trebor : could you comment further on what you mean by "unrigorous" ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian : they are unrigorous because in ordinary analysis $dx$ is not defined. Intuitively we can replace $dx$ by a small $\Delta x$. Then your two intervals are arbitrarily close to each other.